# How to control access to personnal information stored on blockchain (with an educational use case)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, cardano

The following use case would it be possible ?

At a nation level, the government wants its regional educational direction to build a system to certify diplomas. Those diplomas should be stored on a blockchain in such a way that no region could, alone, temper them after they were issued.

The students should be able to give access *temporally* to his or her diplomas, to anyone (eg. employer wanting to recruit).

Please correct me:

I think this should be possible if the data stored on the blockchain was encrypted and if the DAPP was able to generate temporary key to decrypt that data.

Obviously any employer gaining access to the record could make a copy of it, but the point here is that after the expiration of the key's validity, no employer should be able to prove that he owned the real record.

Does that sound like a valid use case for dapps in general. Does it sound even feasible to you ?

Comment: https://atalaprism.io/ is IOHK approach to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following scenario can be suggested as the simplest option:

1. We create a smart contract with 3 methods:

- RegistryRequest(bytes32 info_id, bytes32 user_id, string memory public_cert) payeble
- SendInfo(bytes32 info_id, bytes32 user_id, string file_addr)
- GetInfo(bytes32 info_id, bytes32 user_id) view return(string memory retVal)

2. The consumer calls the method RegistryRequest transfers:

- info_id - the identifier of the required data
- user_id - his unique identifier (e-mail, mobile phone, and so on) ()
- public_cert- his public key OpenSSL
  and attaches a certain amount in Eth to the transaction as payment for the service.

3. Having received the details and payment from the consumer, you:

- create a file with the data he needs
- encrypt this file with the consumer's public key OpenSSL,
- upload it to some web resource or transfer it via IPFS or Ethereum Swarm (or in any other way)
- using the method SendInfo lay out the "address" of the data file (file_addr) in relation to the data and consumer identifiers (info_id, user_id).
  To pay for the transaction, you use a portion of the amount received from the consumer along with the RegistryRequest.

4. The consumer through the method GetInfo using the data identifier (info_id) and his personal identifier (user_id) receives the "address" of the data file, extracts and decrypts it
5. If the data changes, then their changed state is laid out similarly to point 3
6. After the expiration of the data provision period, you stop releasing their update

More complex solutions can, for example, be discussed with experts for free and simulated on a kekker.com

Comment: That a nice answer thank you, showing that the diploma example is not a good one.  So how about changing diploma with medical records and employer with insurance company?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to provide the user with the opportunity for a limited time to observe all changes to the record?
Or do you want to give him a one-time current state of data?

Comment: I would like to give him the opportunity to observe the changes to the record from state x to state y.

Comment: See solution in the answer

Comment: That exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.  Thank you very much.